# Is it safe to assume that the Java JDBC isolation levels are ordered?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

java.sql defines constants like `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` `Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE`.

Is it safe to treat them as the ints they are and do comparisons like `level >= Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`?

Comment: Why would you ever want to compare them except for equality?

Comment: I'm curious why you are asking this question: you can check the values of those constants yourself (eg in the constants list in the javadoc, or in the sources of `java.sql.Connection`) and make the inference yourself based on those values. That said, it is possible that some drivers define custom isolation levels (although that is not allowed by the JDBC specification) where doing such a comparison might break.

Comment: I have some code that wants to verify it is only being run in the context of a transaction that is at least at TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ. So I want the assertion to be that `level >= TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` (rather than, say, `level == TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ || level == TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE`). But it's unclear from the docs if that's OK.

Answer (score 3):

The values are constants and enumerated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE).  It is safe to assume the values will **always be**

```
TRANSACTION_NONE = 0
TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED = 2
TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED = 1
TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ = 4
TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE = 8
```

And if they ever did change, it would break a lot of code (like every JDBC driver for example).